# What exactly does a solution in radicals mean?

Tags: polynomials

I have been reading about the Abel-Ruffini Theorem and how polynomial equations with a degree 5 or higher do not have a solution in radicals. I am not trying to understand the proof of this theorem at this point but simply what the statement of this theorem actually is. I have tried to list my ideas below and I'm hoping someone who understands this concept can verify them for me.

(1) Having a "solution in radicals" means that for any polynomial of that degree, we can find its roots by using only algebraic methods. Because this is true for any polynomial of that degree (regardless of its coefficients), we can build a formula (such as the quadratic formula) where the coefficients are treated as variables and the roots of an equation of that degree are found by simply plugging in its coefficients into that formula.

(2) If such a formula for polynomials of some degree (greater than or equal to 5 according to the Theorem) does not exist, i.e. we cannot find the roots of the equation simply by plugging in the coefficients in a given formula, that does not mean any equation of that degree cannot be solved by algebraic methods but rather that tells us that because there are some polynomials of that degree with certain coefficient values that lead to roots that cannot be so computed, we cannot build a general formula where we could plug in the coefficients of any given polynomial of that degree and we would get the root(s) as we can in polynomials of degrees less than 5.

(3) The Abel-Ruffini Theorem states that all polynomial families characterised by having a degree 5 or higher are included in the description (2) hence the statement: There does not exist a solution in radicals for polynomials of degree 5 and higher.

Comment: A slight nitpick in (b): We can build a formula, we only cannot build a formula with radicals

Comment: I think it's useful to study [Cardano's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_equation) for cubics...the quadratic equation is, perhaps, deceptively simple.  Cardano gives a good sense of the sort of formulas that might, in principle, be involved.

Comment: @Trebor those are the kind of clarifications I am looking for. Thanks.

Comment: Nitpick in (3) - some polynomials do have simple solutions, I.e. $x^5=0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expression “algebraic methods” is rather vague. A solution in radicals is a solution in which a root of a polynomial is obtained from the coefficients of that polynomial using only sums, subtractions, products, divisions, and radicals.

What the Abel-Ruffini theorem states is that there is no solution in radicals for the *general* fifth degree polynomial. In other words, there is no formula (which, again, uses only sums, subtractions, products, divisions, and radicals ) that gives us a root of a fifth degree polynomial and which works for *all* such polynomials.

However, in principle, it would be possible to divide the fifth degree polynomials into several types and to find a solution in radicals for each type. But even that is not true. However, in order to prove that one needs Galois theory.

And it follows from the Abel-Ruffini theorem that, for each $n>4$, there is no solution in radicals for the general $n$<sup>th</sup> degree polynomial.

Comment: The wording that I found kind of confusing was "general fifth degree polynomial". But I think your following sentences made me understand: a solution in radicals  for the general fifth degree polynomial means a solution that can be formulated into a general formula using only the methods you've listed and works for all 5th degree polynomials. Is that accurate?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. With emphasis in *all*.